# File Not Found in Directory

Tags: c#

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Keeps getting the error that file is not found at the very last line.

```
string XMLPackagesDir = "C:\\Users\\ro\\Desktop\\Cl\\Cle\\Xm\\";
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(XMLPackagesDir);
foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
Response i;
FileStream fs = null;
fs = new FileStream("XMLPackagesDir" + fi.Name, FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using a string literal instead of a variable.  Use

```
fs = new FileStream(XMLPackagesDir + fi.Name, FileMode.Open);
```

instead of

```
fs = new FileStream("XMLPackagesDir" + fi.Name, FileMode.Open);
```

or better yet

```
fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(XMLPackagesDir, fi.Name), FileMode.Open);
```

so you don't have to worry about trailing slashes.

Answer (score 2):

you have an object `string XMLPackagesDir`.  But you are using a string on your last line:

```
fs = new FileStream("XMLPackagesDir" + fi.Name, FileMode.Open);
```

Use your object, and per best practices, use the `Path` library:

```
fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(XMLPackagesDir, fi.Name), FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have given the solution at your typo. But I wish to say that 
the FileInfo class has a property named [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname(v=vs.110).aspx), that, as the name explains, contains the full name of the file with its folder name.

So why do you need this string concatenation?

It is just

```
 fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
public static void foo(String path) {
            try {
                DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                foreach (FileInfo fi in DirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)){
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
                    Response i;
                    FileStream fs = null;
                    fs = new FileStream(fi.FullName, FileMode.Open);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```